# Vue router advanced props

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm trying to customize the props object passed by the router to a component.

In my routes I have:

```
{
    path: '/base/fixed/:dynamic',
    component: OfficeActions,
    props: true
},
```

This allows me to access the `dynamic` prop inside de component. However, I would like to do something like this:

```
{
    path: '/base/fixed/:dynamic',
    component: OfficeActions,
    props: {
        custom: 'something_custom_for_this_route',
        dynamic: dynamic // the dynamic parameter from the route (:dynamic)
    }
},
```

Where I would be able to access trow props inside the component: `custom` and `dynamic`. The `custom` prop being defined in my route, and the `dynamic` prop being the value grabbed form the route `:dynamic`.

Is this possible? Any help is appreciated.

With the example above, I get an error since `dynamic` isn't define inside the `props` object.

I have also tried:

```
{
    path: '/base/fixed/:dynamic',
    component: OfficeActions,
    props: {
        custom: 'something_custom_for_this_route',
    }
},
```

and

```
{
    path: '/base/fixed/:dynamic',
    component: OfficeActions,
    props: {
        default: true,
        custom: 'something_custom_for_this_route',
    }
},
```

With these I get `dynamic` as `undefined` inside the component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written in the documentation:

> [You can create a function that returns props](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/passing-props.html#function-mode).

And thus combine the parameters of both types:

```
{
    path: '/base/fixed/:dynamic',
    component: OfficeActions,
    props: function(route) {
      return Object.assign({}, route.params, {
        custom: 'something_custom_for_this_route'
      })
    }
}
```

[ https://jsfiddle.net/uypveLhw/ ]

Comment: Awesome! Thank you.